# Prove that a straight line is the shortest distance between two points?

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Prove that a straight line is the shortest distance between two points 
in $E_3$. Use the following scheme; let $\alpha: [a,b]\to E_3$ be an arbitrary curve segment from $p = \alpha(a) , q = \alpha(b)$.Let $u = (q — p)/||q — p || $.

(a) If $\sigma$ is a straight-line segment from $ p$ to $ q$ , say 
$$\sigma (t) = (1 - t)p + tq ,\quad 0\leq t\leq1$$
show that $L(\sigma ) = d(p,q)$.

What I have done
$$
L(\sigma)=\int_{0}^{1}||\sigma'(t)||dt=\int_{0}^{1}(p^2+q^2)^{1/2}dt=\sqrt{(p^2+q^2)}(1),
$$
$d(p,q)=\sqrt{(b-a)^2+(q-p)^2}$. Where am I doing wrong? It's a problem from O'Neill Elementary Differential Geometry.

Comment: How did you get your expression for $\vert\vert \sigma ' (t) \vert\vert$?

Comment: You should integrate from 0 to 1.

Comment: integrating the speed of curve from a to b,yes t should be from 0 to 1

Comment: But he's integrating the special curve $\sigma$ which is only defined on $[0,1]$.

Comment: It should be $\int_{0}^1$ not $\int_{a}^b$

Comment: You are wrong in asserting that $|\sigma'(t)|^2=p^2+q^2$, for one.

Comment: What does $p^2$ even mean when $p$ is a point?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you,please correct it.or give a hint

Comment: I did give you a hint. What do you think $\sigma'(t)$ is?

Comment: $\sigma $ is a straight line segment from  to q and $\sigma'(t)$ is velocity.and $||\sigma'(t)|| $ is  speed of $\sigma $ at $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that $\sigma'(t)=q-p,$ what is wrong is the norm of this vector, that is not $\sqrt{p^2+q^2},$ but $||q-p||=d(p,q).$

In coordinates, if $p=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $q=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, then $q-p$ is the vector of components $(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$ whose norm is 
$$
\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}=d(p,q).
$$

Comment: i am confused by these $ p=α(a),q=α(b)$

Comment: @Cielo: to visualize, imagine $t\in[a,b]$ is the time, so $p=\alpha(a)$ is the position at the initial time $a$, it is a point in space $\mathbb{E}_3$, while $q=\alpha(b)$ is the position at the final time $b$.

Comment: oh thanks you  are great you gave me good intuition.